# Google Analytics is tracking my css files

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I built a web site using Wordpress and I have added Google analytics source code to the footer of the pages, but when I checked my console I found that Google Anaytics was tracking my css files like it does for pages too !!

Do you have any idea for this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it !

Google Analytics tracks css files beceause they aren't disallowed in "robots.txt" :

**Disallow: /*.css$**

That's it !

Answer (score 1):

This would be a tough one to guess at without additional information, but could it be that the CSS resource is triggering a 404 page?

I'd try copying and pasting the exact URL of the reported CSS file and see if it takes you to the CSS itself or to a WordPress page of some kind.

It's just not possible that (without something strange going on at the server side or a customized Task or GA Plugin) a CSS file is executing the GA JavaScript tracker.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and at the same time I can't share the url because it is for a Professional uses. Yes It's strange a little that GA is tracking my css files !!